# Change laravel errors messages to JSON for API

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

Is there a way to manipulate or change laravel default error messages into JSON response. I am building an API. The current response that I am getting is

```
{
    "email": [
        "The email has already been taken."
    ],
    "phone": [
        "The phone has already been taken."
    ]
}
```

I want it to be like this

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "username",
      "message": "The username field is required."
    },
    {
      "field": "password",
      "message": "The password field is required."
    }
  ]
}




$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:50|unique:customers',
            'phone' => 'required|string|max:10|min:10|unique:customers',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);



        if ($validator->fails()) {
           return response()->json($validator->messages(), 200);
        }
```

Comment: Both code is JSON.

Comment: I think he wants to put the errors array inside a errors key.

Comment: @Phiter yes...any solution??

Comment: How do you return those errors?

Comment: @Phiter laravel does that automatically.. I cant even access the array/json that is being returned.

Comment: @Phiter I have updated my question please have a look

Comment: Then you have the error structure in the $validator->messages. Just manipulate it and convert it to your needs.

Comment: And what version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the errors from the messageBag and format them as you wish:

```
$errors = [];
foreach($validator->getMessageBag()->toArray() as $key=>$messages) {
    $errors[$key] = $messages[0];
}
return response()->json($errors, 200);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get object as you given first example you can change it by `for..in` loop like this

```js
var response = {
    "email": [
        "The email has already been taken."
    ],
    "phone": [
        "The phone has already been taken."
    ]
};

var allError = [];
for(let i in response){
   allError.push({
      field: i,
      message: response[i][0]
    });
}
var errors = {errors:allError};
console.log(errors);
```

You should not change from php/laravel, because then you will not be able to show multiple errors for single input.

Also never change base code which can also work for web. You can't think for only API, It can also be used for web.

Comment: Never fix something in local which can be avoided in server.

Comment: @Amarnasan : Also never change base code which can also work for web. You can't think for only API, it can also be used for web.

Comment: @Amarnasan Neither you nor me completely know the business logic, so I suggest to not change base code from laravel.